# ImportError: bad magic number in 'time': b'\x03\xf3\r\n' in Django

Tags: python, django

I got this error while running the Django app file that I had downloaded from GitHub. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Delete all `.pyc` files you downloaded with it.

Answer (score 74):

Please go to your home directory.  And then:

```
 sudo find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*.pyc" -delete`, why `sudo`?

Comment: sudo "in your home directory" is not necessary

Answer (score 26):

Finally, I found the answer, The project has .pyc files, which holds the previous version information and time date, so this error. After deleting those files I got the output.

Answer (score 24):

You can delete all the .pyc files in your folder to resolve it.

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

Comment: sudo find . -name \*.pyc -delete

Comment: @Hans You are both needlessly adding sudo to a command and also failing to properly quote an argument that might end up expanding. The original command is fine.

Answer (score 16):

Included in your checkout are `.pyc` files. These are *byte cache files*, storing cached bytecode so Python can avoid having to parse and compile the source files. Unless you plan to distribute a project without source files, these should not be included.

Just delete all `.pyc` files located in the same directory as `.py` files.

The "magic number" in the error message is a version number for the bytecode stored, and specific Python versions only work with specific bytecode magic numbers; the number in your error is equal to 62211 in decimal (when interpreted as a little-endian number), which shows the [`.pyc` files were created with a Python 2.7 interpreter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/680d26e3b6b3fcd2deadd392d837325e2d1bb652/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L200).

Python 3.2 switched to storing `.pyc` files in separate `__pycache__` directories and including the Python version in the filename. However, any `.pyc` files still located next to the `.py` files are supported still to allow for bytecode-only releases. It's safe to delete such files because if you were to use a Python 2.7 interpreter in future, then the files will be re-created.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the .pyc files created in your directory .'

ex : i have gitlab.py and gitlab.pyc

later i renamed it into gitlab-api.py

But while running python file , it is using gitlab.pyc so

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "gitlab-api.py", line 1, in 
> import gitlab
> ImportError: bad magic number in 'gitlab': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

it worked correctly when i deleted the gitlab.pyc

Answer (score 4):

you will need to delete any pyc. pyc is the cache of your app. delete all files that end with .pyc and rerun your app.

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Windows you have to delete Python's older versions, then you are ready to use `pip` again. This is the best method, without errors.

Comment: You can also use [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) or [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to better manage your installed software on windows, and then the process of installing or uninstalling python will be significantly better.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the class name or file name that you are importing, this fixed my issue.