# How to install tkinter in python 3.7 fedora?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fedora, turtle-graphics

I have tried to install tkinter in python 3 as
sudo yum install tkinter

But it's saying that could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter from versions no matching distribution found on tkinter

I was trying to run turtle programs in python script. But it's running on python prompt when I am coming to the python script its not running. So i tried to download tkinter.

Comment: Please show the error output. Provide as many details as you can.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/home/priyabrata/MY files/python/turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    wn=turtle.Screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Screen'

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ don't know what happened but after restarting my system .the python3-tkinter is already installed . But when I am trying to run the turtle program its showing the upper traceback

Comment: Show the code of `turtle.py`

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ   import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle()

alex.forward(50)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)

wn.mainloop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: comments section]

You've named your file `turtle.py`, and when you write `import turtle`, `turtle.py` is attempting to import itself. You can solve this by renaming `turtle.py` to something else, such as `myturtle.py`.

Comment: I had done that also .i named it as alex.py .. but something else is happening .. traceback is like ..14
priyabrata ray
PRIYABRATA RAY
Priyabrata Ray
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alex.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
ImportError: bad magic number in 'turtle': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: And also I don't know about first 4 line .. and where it is coming from

Comment: Try removing `.pyc` files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477683/importerror-bad-magic-number-in-time-b-x03-xf3-r-n-in-django

Comment: Okay and please tell me about those first 4 lines .. where did they coming from .. not only in this program .. in most of the error cases those line prints .I don't know why

Comment: You can google for what "traceback" and "ImportError" means. It's all been written about.